# flutter box won't save the data

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am trying to store logged user data in Hive storage but my user box return `null`

**Code**

`main.dart`

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(UsermodelAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Usermodel>('user');
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

`login.dart`

> After user successfully logged in by server I'm trying to store data before redirecting user

```
print('box:::: ${user.name}'); // print (admin) - user name coming from server

//store data in storage
var userData = Usermodel()
  ..name = user.name
  ..email = user.email
  ..createdAt = user.createdAt
  ..approved = user.approved;
final box = Hive.box<Usermodel>('user');
box.add(userData);

print('box:::: ${box.get('name')}'); // print (null)
```

**any idea why I cannot store my user data?**

Comment: Have you tried awaiting the adding of user data? `await box.add(userData);`

Comment: @rickimaru still getting `null`

Comment: `get(...)` needs a key. Use the key returned by `add(...)`. Ref: [get](https://pub.dev/documentation/hive/latest/hive/Box/get.html) and [add](https://pub.dev/documentation/hive/latest/hive/BoxBase/add.html)

Comment: @rickimaru `name` is a key in my user model as you can see several line above `..name = xxxx`

Comment: But it is not treated as a key in your box. To set it as a custom key, use `put(userData.name, userData);`. Then read it via `get(userData.name);`.

Comment: Ok, so this is how it works now `print('box:::: ${box.get(0)!.name}');`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `add()` to store your data in a `Hive` box, will give it an incremental index as it's key, so you can imagine that your `Hive` box is like a list, so this:

```
box.add(data); will add data to the box with a 0 index since it's the first and only element in the box.
box.get('name'); // will return null because that key doesn't exist
```

there are two solutions for that case.

Either saving the `data` in the box using `put()` with providing a "name" key like this:

```
box.put('name', data); 
box.get('name');  //  will return data.
```

or trying to get the `data` with that index key with the `getAt()` like this:

```
 box.add(data); 
    box.getAt(0);  //  will return data. (assuming that it's the first element so it's index is 0)
```